# Keep track of rewards for refered users

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to reward users based on referals. The catch is that the new registered users will hopefully reward the referer of its referer too (by half the reward).

Lets say A refers B (B signs up), A gets 1 point. B refers C (C signs up), B gets 1 point and A gets 0.5 points (because B was refered by A). 
So: A gets 1 + 0.5 points, B gets 1 point (for refering C).

B refers D, C refers D (D signs up)
B gets 1 point (C gets no points because B refered D first)

and so on ...

I think of tracking it like this:

```
class User
  def initialize
    refered_by = nil
    refered = []
    points = nil
  end
end
```

For the example the referals would be saved like this:

```
A.refered_by = nil
A.refered = [B]
B.refered_by = A
B.refered = [C,D]
C.refered_by = B
D.refered_by = B
```

Of course, no sign up gives no points.

Something like this to calculate the points:

```rb
def points
  direct_refs = User.where(refered_by: self.id)
  total_points = direct_refs.count
  direct_refs.each do |i|
    next_level_refs = User.where(refered_by: i)
    total_points += next_level_refs.count / 2
  end
  # this should go deep until the user gets all the earned points
  return total_points
end
```

Upon signup, calculating points for the example would be like this:

```
A.points -> 1 + 0.5 + 0.5  (1 for B, 0.5 for C, 0.5 for D)
B.points -> 1 + 1  (1 for C, 1 for D)
```

I also thought about using trees, but couldn't figure out how.

Any insight, or documentation I could read is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works out!

**What if you made a table in the database called referrals that basically stores one column, a json hash with each value being an array, that keeps a record of all of the referrals and users. So for example, `{A: [B, E], B: [C], C: [D], D: [] E: []}` Then when calculating points parse it by taking all of the points that the person they referred has and multiply it by half. So A would get 1 point for referring B but it would also be plus the .75 because B would have referred C who referred D. So if you trace that back, C = 1 + ((D's referrals, 0)/2), and B = 1 + ((C's referrals, 1)/2), and A = 1 + ((B's referrals, 1.5)/2) and then A is equal to 1.75, however since I also added E, it would be another 1 point.**

I hope this is what you are looking for! If not let me know!

C = 1, B = 1 + (1/2), A = 2 + (1.5/2)

Comment: Thanks Luke. I'm usin Rails and a DB. The catch is how to reward the users who referred the ones who referred others by half depending on the referal degree. So A refers B, B refers C, C refers D. Upon D signup A gets 1 + 0.5 + 0.25 (if B & C signed up too)